# Given a matrix representation of a system of equations, its rank, and a solution; find the general form of the solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let A be a matrix representation of a linear system of equations (image of the matrix is given below) and it is given that $rank(A)=2$ and \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix} is a solution vector to the system of equations. Find a general solution to the system of equations.

Here is the matrix representation of the system of equations:

[image: Matrix representation of the system of equations]

I tried using a theorem that states that $rank(A)=n-dim(P)$ where $n$ is the number of variables, and $dim(P)$ is the dimension of the solution vector space. In this case, $rank(A)=2$ and $n=3$ so $dim(P)=1$, that means the solution vector space has only one element in its basis, implying that the general solution vector is of the form \begin{bmatrix}t\\2t\\3t\end{bmatrix}

I do not know whether this is correct.

Comment: This is not quite correct. You're right that the dimension of the solution space is $1$, but the solution set is not necessary a one-dimensional *vector space*, i.e. it is not necessary the set of multiples of a single vector. Rather, it is a one-dimensional *affine space*, i.e. it is the set of vectors of the form $p + tv$, where $p$ is a *particular solution* to your system – in your case, $p = (1, 2, 3)$ – and $v$ is in the *null space* of the matrix of coefficients of your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved, and the solution vector is (1+2t,2+2t,3-t).